# How do I get images from the MLS RETS feed provided by CRMLS (formerly Carets MLS)?

Tags: php, rets

I am getting this as response when using the GetObject() feature of the RETS feed:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Success] => 
            [Content-Type] => text/xml
            [MIME-Version] => 1.0
            [Length] => 53
            [Data] => 

            [ReplyCode] => 20401
            [ReplyText] => Invalid Type
        )

)
```

GetObject() works for most RETS feeds, but I'm getting errors with CRMLS. How do I get images from the MLS RETS feed provided by CRMLS (formerly Carets MLS)?

Comment: I am not getting the image urls on the response, the data field is empty. I am passing 'OpenHouseKey' for resource OpenHouse, 'ListingKey' for resource Property and 'MediaKey' for resource 'Media'

Answer (score 5):

There could be a number of causes for this.

First, going only by the error message, the server is suggesting that the given `Type` attribute in the request is incorrect.  Using PHRETS, this is the value of the 2nd argument in the `GetObject` request.  Check http://www.retsmd.com with your RETS credentials, select one of the Property classes, and when the list of fields loads, a "View Object Types" link should appear at the top of the table.  Clicking that will display the available types that you can request.  `Photo` is the most common but they may not provide it by that name.

In some other (though rare) cases, RETS servers may not provide access to media through GetObject.  Instead, they may have a "Media" resource where you'd retrieve information about objects the same way you would with other data (like listings or agents rosters).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks a lot. I have contacted the MLS, and they advised me the same. The RETS server does not support the GetObject method to retrieve photos. Instead, we ll need to query the Media resource to retrieve a property’s photos.

Take a ListingKey from a Property class search and take that value to search in the Media class using the ClassKey field. This will return all the applicable Media records for a particular listing. This includes supplements, images etc
The media records are stored as MediaURLs. It is  recommended  to download the photos locally to avoid expired URL.

Comment: CRMLS is one among the rare cases, but media resource provides low-resolution images which are blurry. Is there any way to get high resolution images?